# Mongoldb, issue with deleting and saving data to a collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am having some issue with removing objects in my database. I have a collection called menus which consists of several object where each object is an item in the menu. Here is how it looks :

```
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("583b7577e1206be8ee79f062"),
   "restID":"583972080daa6ece0960778c",
   "itemName":"buffallo chicken wings",
   "subType":"Appetizers/Starters",
   "cuisine":"American",
   "description":"descritption of buffallo chicken wings",
   "duration":"All",
   "quantity":"6",
   "cost":"10.95",
   "__v":0
}
```

Now I have a X button next to each item in my frontend. The code below shows how I am trying to delete an item (when user clicks the X button) on my server side. After debugging this I observed that it is splicing the object that I want to delete but it is not updating the database. I don't understand why. Am I doing something wrong?

```
module.exports.removemenu = function(req, res) {
    var menuId = req.body.itemId;
    Menu.find({}, function(err, results){
        results.map(function(menu, index){
            if(menu._id == menuId) {
                results.splice(index, 1);
            }
            menu.save();
        })
        res.json({res: 'success', data: results});

    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you upserting the changes to the database afterwards?

Comment: how? Sorry I have just started learning this I am not sure what you mean. Please can you explain.

Answer (score 0):

Use remove command to delete record from collection
db.restaurants.remove( { "borough": "Manhattan" } )